# How can I filter an SQL query with a GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to formulate an SQL query for a messaging system that will return a list of all threads which have a status of 'OPEN' and whose last message was not posted by a user in a certain group.

The tables involved in the query are:

```
threads
-------
threadId
timestamp
subject
status
clientId

messages
--------
messageId
userId
messagebody
timestamp
threadId

users
-----
userId
username
groupId
```

The current query is:

```
SELECT threadId, timestamp, subject, status, clientId 
FROM threads
WHERE status='OPEN' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

which works fine; but I now have a new requirement - if the last message in the thread was posted by a user with a `groupId` of 1 then it should NOT be in the result set.

Including the information I need is simple enough:

```
SELECT threadId, timestamp, subject, status, clientId 
FROM threads
INNER JOIN messages USING(threadId)
INNER JOIN users USING(userId)
WHERE status='OPEN' 
GROUP BY threadId
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

but at this point I get stuck, because I can't figure out how to get the query to filter out threads based on the `messages.userId` with the highest `timestamp` within a particular group. I've looked at `HAVING` and all the aggregate functions and nothing seems to fit the bill.

**Edit**

I may not have been clear enough, so I'll try to illustrate with an example.

Here's some example data:

**threads**

```
threadId | timestamp | subject | status | clientId
--------------------------------------------------
1        | 1         | One     | OPEN   | 1
2        | 10        | Two     | OPEN   | 4
3        | 26        | Three   | OPEN   | 19
4        | 198       | Four    | OPEN   | 100
```

**messages**

```
messageId | userId | messagebody | timestamp | threadId
-------------------------------------------------------
1         | 3      | Hello, World| 1         | 1
2         | 1      | Hello       | 3         | 1
3         | 1      | ^&%&6       | 10        | 2
4         | 2      | Test        | 12        | 2
5         | 4      | Hi mum      | 26        | 3
6         | 1      | More tests  | 100       | 4
```

**users**

```
userId | username | groupId
---------------------------
1      | Gareth   | 1
2      | JimBob   | 2
3      | BillyBob | 2
4      | Bod      | 3
```

In this example dataset threads 1 and 4 should be eliminated from the query because user `Gareth` (a member of group 1) is the last one to post to them (messageId 2 in threadId 1, and messageId 5 in threadId 4). So the result set should only have the thread data (threadId, timestamp, subject, status and clientId) for threads 2 and 3.

I've created an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d86) for this test data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: There are two relatively easy ways: either using `HAVING` or using this result as a new table in a subquery.

Comment: HAVING groupID != 1 does not solve your issue?. Its very bad performance speaking (see below, filtering them already in join is faster), but should work overall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Does adding `LIMIT 1` to your query solve your problem?</strike>

```
SELECT threadId, timestamp, subject, status, clientId  
FROM threads 
INNER JOIN messages USING(threadId) 
INNER JOIN users USING(userId) 
WHERE status='OPEN'  
GROUP BY threadId 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Or changing the where clause to

```
WHERE status='OPEN' and groupID<>1
```

I think this is what you want?

```
select * from threads
where threadId not in
(
    select messages.threadId
    from messages
        inner join (select threadId, MAX(timestamp) maxtime from messages group by threadId) t
            on messages.threadId = t.threadId
            and messages.timestamp = t.maxtime
    where messages.userId=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `LIMIT 1` will just return one result. I want all threads that meet the criteria. Adding `groupId<>1` to the query eliminates all messages that were posted by a user in group 1, but I want to eliminate the whole thread - and only if the last message posted in that thread was posted by a user in group 1. So this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT threadId, timestamp, subject, status, clientId 
FROM threads t
INNER JOIN messages m
  ON t.threadId = m.threadId
INNER JOIN users u
  ON m.userId = u.userId
  and u.groupId != 1  --placed the groupId filter here.
WHERE status='OPEN' 
GROUP BY threadId
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Edit, this appears to give you what you need:

```
SELECT t.threadId, 
  t.timestamp, 
  t.subject, 
  t.status, 
  t.clientId
FROM threads t
INNER JOIN messages m
  ON t.threadId = m.threadId
INNER JOIN users u
  ON m.userId = u.userId
WHERE status='OPEN' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (select t1.threadid
                  FROM threads t1
                  INNER JOIN messages m
                    ON t1.threadId = m.threadId
                  INNER JOIN users u
                    ON m.userId = u.userId
                  where u.groupid = 1
                     and t.threadid = t1.threadid)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b83e6/15)

Comment: Thanks for answering. This doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. It removes all messages posted by a user in group 1, but I want to eliminate all *threads* where the last message was posted by a user in group 1.

Comment: @Gareth can you post some sample data and the expected results?  It would be helpful or even better create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: I've just added a simple example to try and illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @Gareth and what do you want the final result to be?

Comment: I should just get the data for threads 2 and 3 in my example. I'll add that into the question now.

Comment: I've added an SQL fiddle of the example to the question.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for all your help so far. This is very close to what I need, but it eliminates threads where a user in group 1 has posted at all - even if they weren't the last person to post in that thread. I've added an extra message to thread 2 in my test case and sqlfiddle example. Thread 2 data should still be returned in that case and your query eliminates thread 2.